# Replace Futures.successfulAsList with Java 8 CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, guava, completable-future

I am Looking for canonical code to replace Guava's [`Futures.successfulAsList()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)) with Java 8's `CompletableFuture` code.

I think [`CompletableFuture.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) seems like a replacement for [`Futures.allAsList()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)), but I don't see anything quite like `successfulAsList()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CompletableFuture.allOf(…)` is actually closer to `successfulAsList()` than `allAsList()`.

Indeed, `allOf()` only completes after all the given futures have completed, be it with a value or an exception. You can then inspect each future to check how it completed (e.g. in a following `thenAccept()`/`thenApply()`).

`allAsList()` does not have a close equivalent in `CompletableFuture` because it should fail as soon as any of the input futures fails. However, you could implement it with a combination of `allOf()` and chaining each input future with an `exceptionally()` that would make the future returned by `allOf()` immediately fail:

```
CompletableFuture<String> a = …, b = …, c = …;
CompletableFuture<Void> allWithFailFast = CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b, c);
Stream.of(a, b, c)
    .forEach(f -> f.exceptionally(e -> {
        allWithFailFast.completeExceptionally(e);
        return null;
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks Didier, that's helpful.