# How to implement CompletableFuture.allOf() that completes exceptionally once any of the futures fail?

Tags: java, completable-future

I want to implement a hybrid of `CompletableFuture.allOf()` and `CompletableFuture.anyOf()` where the returned future completes successfully as soon as all of the elements complete successfully, or it completes exceptionally (with the same exception) as soon as any of the elements complete exceptionally. In the case of multiple elements failing, returning the exception of any of them is sufficient.

### Use-case

I have a task that needs to aggregate sub-results returned by a list of `CompletableFuture`s, but that task should stop waiting as soon as any of them fails. I understand that the sub-tasks will keep on running and that's okay.

### Related questions

I found [Waiting on a list of Future](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19348248/14731) which initially seems like a duplicate question but the accepted answer uses `CompletionService` which requires `Callable` or `Runnable` as input. I am looking for a solution that takes already-running `CompletionStage`s as input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question is actually very similar to [Replace Futures.successfulAsList with Java 8 CompletableFuture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330764/replace-futures-successfulaslist-with-java-8-completablefuture/43342128#43342128)

Although the question is not exactly the same, the same answer (from myself) should satisfy your needs.

You can implement this with a combination of `allOf()` and chaining each input future with an `exceptionally()` that would make the future returned by `allOf()` immediately fail:

```
CompletableFuture<String> a = …, b = …, c = …;
CompletableFuture<Void> allWithFailFast = CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b, c);
Stream.of(a, b, c)
    .forEach(f -> f.exceptionally(e -> {
        allWithFailFast.completeExceptionally(e);
        return null;
    }));
```

Comment: i see that even if one of them fails (say a from ur example) - the other 2 are still picked up the executor service. are tasks marked as failure not automatically removed from the threadpool ??

Comment: for a true fail-fast u will have to cancel each of the tasks in ```f.exceptionally```

Comment: Indeed, `CompletableFuture` does not provide any mechanism to cancel the task behind it. This is due to the fact that it does not hold a reference to that task, and there might actually be no such concrete task since you can create a `CompletableFuture` programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the job:

```
/**
 * @param arrayOfFutures an array of futures to wait on
 * @return a {@code CompletableFuture} that completes successfully once all elements have completed successfully, or completes
 * exceptionally after any of the elements has done the same
 * <br>{@code @throws NullPointerException} if {@code arrayOfFutures} is null
 */
public CompletableFuture<Void> waitForAllButAbortOnFirstException(CompletableFuture<?>... arrayOfFutures)
{
    if (arrayOfFutures == null)
      return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new NullPointerException("arrayOfFutures may not be null"));
    if (arrayOfFutures.length == 0)
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    return CompletableFuture.anyOf(arrayOfFutures).
        thenApply(unused ->
        {
            // Remove any futures that completed normally and try again
            return Arrays.stream(arrayOfFutures).
                filter(element -> !element.isDone() || element.isCompletedExceptionally()).
                toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
        }).
        thenCompose(remainingFutures -> waitForAllButAbortOnFirstException(remainingFutures));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gili's answer, I wrote up this code that I'm using - I think its basically the same but is simple to read.

```java
/**
 * Wait for all of the futures to complete successfully unless at least one of
 * them has failed (completed with an exception) - then complete
 * immediately with the first exception received.
 * @param futures list of completable futures to wait on
 * @return a future that will complete successfully as soon as all submitted
 *   futures has completed successfully, or will complete exceptionally as soon
 *   as one of the submitted futures has completed exceptionally. 
 */
public static CompletableFuture<Void>
        allOfUnlessFailed(CompletableFuture<?> ...futures) {
    CompletableFuture<?>[] rest = Stream.of(futures)
            .filter(f -> !f.isDone() || f.isCompletedExceptionally())
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
    if (rest.length == 0)
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    return CompletableFuture.anyOf(rest)
            .thenCompose(__ -> allOfUnlessFailed(rest));
}
```

I'm avoiding the input null/empty checks as they wouldn't change the behavior, except that providing `null` should definitely throw an NPE right then and there, like Java core code does, and not return a failed future.