# CompletableFuture how to return first FALSE or wait until all are completed to return TRUE

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a bit of an odd situation that doesn’t seem to allow this peg to fit into any of the widely established CompletableFuture holes.

- Within a primary method that is evaluating returned booleans, I am wanting to allow calls to three different methods to complete asynchronously. Each of these three methods can return either a TRUE or a FALSE.
- If *any* return a FALSE, I want the evaluation to drop the remainder and simply return that FALSE value. The point being, it can be *any* of the three, not necessarily the first.
- But most importantly, I need the evaluation to wait until *all three* return TRUE before actually returning TRUE. This is *critically important*.

Right now, I am using a basic `&&` chain to make this evaluation:

```
public boolean evaluateChecks() {
    return checkOne().Join() && checkTwo().Join() && checkThree().Join();
}
```

However this still does things in a specific order - if `checkThree()` is the first to return a FALSE value, it still has to wait until the prior two have provided their values before it gets evaluated, due to how the `&&` fall-through works.

Right now all three methods return `CompletableFuture<Boolean>`, but I have no problem reverting these back into normal methods in order to run a `CompletableFuture` in the primary method that evaluates them.

I have looked at [quite a few examples](https://dzone.com/articles/20-examples-of-using-javas-completablefuture), but none seem to provide me with the functionality I need.

Comment: Have you considered `CountDownLatch`?

Comment: I am unable to implement `Runnable` in this class or cleave this code off into a separate class, due to other specifics of the project. Could I still implement `CountDownLatch` without implementing `Runnable`?

Comment: `.Join()` ? what method is this?

Comment: Have you tried using `cancel()` instead of returning false? And then do some action on cancel event? Have you tries also this `anyOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from the answer by Didier L here:

- [How to implement CompletableFuture.allOf() that completes exceptionally once any of the futures fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621510/how-to-implement-completablefuture-allof-that-completes-exceptionally-once-any)

Instead of using `exceptionally` and `completeExceptionally`, use `thenAccept` to `complete` the `CompletableFuture` returned by `allOf()`.

For example, save the futures because you're about to chain actions on them:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> a = checkOne(), b = checkTwo(), c = checkThree();
```

Use [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) to wait for all of them to complete (presumably you're not expecting failures/exceptions) and transform the `Void` result into the expected `Boolean` value of `true`.

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> allWithFailFast = CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b, c).thenApply(__ -> a.join() && b.join() && c.join());
// if there is an exception, it'll be propagated to the future returned by thenApply
```

With the returned `CompletableFuture` above, you can now `complete` it faster if any of the original futures completes with `false`.

```
Stream.of(a, b, c).forEach(f -> f.thenAccept(result -> {
    if (!result) {
        allWithFailFast.complete(false);
    }
}));
```

Depending on the order of completions and their result, either the `allOf` future will complete first with a result of evaluating the futures or one of the futures will return `false` and cause the `allWithFailFast` to complete with `false`.

If multiple futures complete with `false`, only the first call to

```
allWithFailFast.complete(false);
```

will do anything, the others will essentially be ignored.

Comment: Hmmm... when I try to put a return inside of the foreach, I get an `unexpected return value`. Not entirely sure how to return either the early FALSE or the final TRUE. Or do I just return `allWithFailFast.join()` at the very end?

Comment: @R.Kåbis `forEach` accepts a `Consumer`. You don't need to return anything in there. The `allWithFailFast.complete(false)` accomplishes the fail-fast behavior.

Comment: Well, the overall method is throwing an error because it has no boolean to report back with. Nothing is being explicitly returned. From what I understand, I will need to put a `return allWithfailFast.join()` at the end of the method, _after_ the `Stream.of()`.

Comment: @R.Kåbis What method is that? If you need to return a `CompletableFuture`, then return the `allWithFailFast`, which is what you should be working with to get the final result.

Comment: If you look at my original code, the `evaluateChecks()` that contains the evaluation of the checks needs to return a plain boolean. And a plain boolean is what the code at the far end is expecting.

Comment: Call `join` on that future.