# CompletableFuture: anyOne which method is called and how can I get the desirable value

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I need to call a method with different input parameters (like id) asynchronously, the method returns true or false, and the false output is not desirable, so I should wait for a true output. As soon as I get a true one, I do not care about the other calls, just I need to know the true output is corresponding with which input (id).

I call this piece of code, how should I know the input id of responded method? It might have a more completableFuture. The next question is in case of getting false, how can I skip and wait for getting true, because I need to recieve true from one of the myService.myMethod(int input)?

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myService.myMethod(1));
CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture2= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myService.myMethod(2));
CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture3= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myService.myMethod(3));
CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture4= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myService.myMethod(4));

CompletableFuture<Object> result =
        CompletableFuture.anyOf(completableFuture, completableFuture2,completableFuture3,,completableFuture4).thenApply(s -> s);
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture` isn't really fit for your requirement (the first with a specific result) because all of its combining functionality is either "wait for all" (e.g. `thenCombine`), or "wait for any, but the status is ignored" (`anyOf`). https://openjdk.org/jeps/428 would provide a better solution, but that won't be finalized for at least one or two more Java releases. A custom solution is probably needed.

Comment: If you know that at least one of these results will be true, you could use an `AtomicReference` to store the first result (`compareAndSet(null, id)` will ignore any update except for the first), and a `CountDownLatch` with count 1 to wait for the result. If all results can be false, you'll need some more complex code, because the `CountDownLatch` may never have its `countDown` method called.

Comment: In the case, all results can be false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CompletableFuture how to return first FALSE or wait until all are completed to return TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999254/completablefuture-how-to-return-first-false-or-wait-until-all-are-completed-to-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that each result can be false makes this a bit tricky, because you can't abort too early. The following should work; it lets each `CompletableFuture` publish its results to a queue, as well as a sentinel value that indicates that all work is done. You then take the first element from the queue that was successful; if there is none, you know that all results are false if you read the sentinel value.

```java
record Result (int id, boolean value) {}
final Result sentinel = new Result(Integer.MIN_VALUE, false);

// one more than the number of results, for the sentinel
BlockingDeque<Result> results = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(5);
// the number of results exactly
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(4);

CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    Record record = new Record(1, myService.myMethod(1));
    results.add(record);
    latch.countDown();
});
// etc for 2-4
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // log or something?
    } finally {
        results.add(sentinel);
    }
});

Result result = results.take();
while (!result.value() && !result.equals(sentinel)) {
    result = results.take();
}
```

The sentinel is only added once each result has been published (due to the `CountDownLatch`), ensuring it's always the last element.

When the loop ends, if `result.equals(sentinel)`, all results were false. Otherwise, `result` contains the id for the first available successful result.